# How to have a key with multiple values in a map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map like this

```
Map map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
map.put("a",10);
map.put("a",20);
map.put("a",30);
map.put("b",10);

System.out.println("There are "+map.size()+" elements in the map.");
System.out.println("Content of Map are...");
Set s=map.entrySet();
Iterator itr=s.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue()+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
}
```

Output of the above program is

```
There are 2 elements in the map.
Content of Map are...
b   10  104
a   30  127
```

Now I want that key a should have multiple values like

```
a 10
a 20
a 30
```

So that I should get all the values associated by a. Please advise how can I achieve that same thing. By nesting of collections, I want key 'a' to have all the three values.

Answer (score 14):

Have you checked out [Guava Multimaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) ?

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K, V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

If you really want to use standard collections (as suggested below), you'll have to store a collection per key e.g.

```
map = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
```

Note that the first time you enter a new key, you'll have to create the new collection (`List`, `Set` etc.) before adding the first value.

Comment: I was looking in java itself Please advise in java

Comment: Guava is a widely used Java library. Note however my comment above re. collections within maps

Answer (score 4):

To implement what you want using the Java standard library, I would use a map like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> multiValueMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
```

Then you can add values:

```
multiValueMap.put("a", new ArrayList<Integer>());
multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(10));
multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(20));
multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(30));
```

If this results uncomfortable for you, consider wrapping this behaviour in a dedicated Class, or using a third-party solution, as others have suggested here ([Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)).

Comment: Hi think01 it is throwing complile time error on add some thing related to casting please advise

Comment: I forgot the generic map declaration, now it's correct. Let's try and let me know.

Comment: yeah it works thanks a lot!! but is not there any other way I was thinking to avoid the array list..!!

Comment: With standard Java library, I cannot think of a solution ready out-of-the-box, you should use a third-party library. Anyway, if you resolved your original issue, please consider to elect your best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put an `ArrayList` instance in the value part.

```
void addValue(Map map, Object key, Object value) {
    Object obj = map.get(key);
    List list;
    if (obj == null) {  
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();  
    } else {
        list = ((ArrayList) obj);
    }
    list.add(value);
    map.put(key, list);
}
```

For More Info check [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/385085/java/java/Implementing-HashMap-multiple-values-key).

Comment: Hi D3EP4K please post the code that will make understanding more clear

Comment: Put this function in your code and call addValue(map,new String("a"),new Integer(10)) instead of calling map.put("a",10)

Comment: According to the approach mentioned in the question, the new value replaces the old one.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ignore the generic parameters. What you have is

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

if you want to code the solution yourself, you need

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Anyhow, the preffered way is to use a [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Map with value type as list of values..For example, in your map, while adding an entry, you will put key as "a" and you will have to add it's value as a list of Integer , having all the required values, like 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

For a Map with entries with same key, has no sense to use `get()` .But as long as you use `iterator()` or `entrySet()` this should work:

```
class HashMap<String, String> {

  Set<Entry<String, String>> entries;
  @Override
  public Set<Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
    return entries;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return entries.size();
  }

  public String put(String key, String value) {
    if (entries == null) {
      entries = new AbstractSet<Entry<String, String>>() {

        ArrayList<Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator() {
          return list.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
          return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry) {
          return list.add(stringStringEntry);
        }
      };
    }
    StatusHandler.MyEntry entry = new StatusHandler.MyEntry();
    entry.setKey(key);
    entry.setValue(value);
    entries.add(entry);
    return value;
  }
};
```

TL;DR So, what is it useful for? That comes from a hack to redmine-java-api to accept complex queries based on form params:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18358659/848072

https://github.com/albfan/RedmineJavaCLI/commit/2bc51901f2f8252525a2d2258593082979ba7122