# How to get issues from a project that have status "in progress" using Redmine REST API

Tags: api, rest, query-string, redmine

I am trying to get specific issues from a plan.io project using the Redmine REST API. I want to list issues from a project that have the status of "in progress" or "to estimate". But I am not sure what kind of query string to write. I cant find any thing in API documentation on the redmine site.

Here is how to get all the issues from a project.

```
http://someurl.com/issues.json?key=185f14564g65f4g65df4g46570a0eb4267&project_id=2
```

But how do I get only the issues from a project that have status equal to "in progress" or "resolved" etc. I know how to get IDs for the statuses but not sure how write the query. This is what I tried but didnt work.

```
http://someurl.com/issues.json?key=185f14564g65f4g65df4g46570a0eb4267&project_id=2&issue_status_id=2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) says there's a **status_id** parameter for list only issues for a given status id. Example:

http://demo.redmine.org/issues.xml?project_id=16992&status_id=2

Tthe **issue_statuses** service can tell you what are the statuses codes

http://demo.redmine.org/issue_statuses.xml

You can set several search values for status with the following syntax:

[http://demo.redmine.org/issues.xml?f[]=status_id&op[status_id]=%3D&v[status_id][]=2&v[status_id][]=3](http://demo.redmine.org/issues.xml?f%5B%5D=status_id&op%5Bstatus_id%5D==&v%5Bstatus_id%5D%5B%5D=2&v%5Bstatus_id%5D%5B%5D=3)

I have to admit it was not mentioned in the documentation, but I found it by setting the filters in the web interface, and than modify the url to call the webservice with the same parameters.

Comment: http://demo.redmine.org/issues.xml?project_id=16992& **status_id** =2. I swear I tried this yesterday it was not working, but working fine now. I am going to test this further and will mark your answer correct.

Comment: Can we search 'test' or something else keyword.